# Transpose thing in Google Sheets

Tags: spreadsheet, transpose

I have question about transpose in Google Spreadsheets

I have source and expectation result in my file, maybe you will easily understand after open my sample file

Here is the link :
[TRANSPOSE SAMPLE FILE](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1mCU1cTaizuDHX5iXJVEIS-ueaqZnNW1cP93_NMXt91c/edit#gid=0)

Thank You!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
=ArrayFormula(QUERY(SPLIT(FLATTEN(A3:A&"♦"&B3:F),"♦"),"select * where Col2 is not null",0))
```